# Both day and night at the same time in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I turn `/gamerule doDaylightCycle` and set it to false while it's day time, will I be able to find a part of the world where it would be night time.

The reason for this is I have multiple vanilla games and I would like one game in the night time setting and one in the day time setting.

At the moment I have one game under the shadow of a block of land to give it he night feel.  I'm thinking there is a better way either through commands or other vanilla way.

Comment: This is impossible with vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have day and night at the same time in different areas of a map.
The whole minecraft world has the same daylight cycle - not possible.

Answer (score -2):

I would try the /execute command to make it night when you enter a certain area. I'm not sure this will work correctly because I'm not good at commands.

Play around with it for a while to see if it will do some good.